# How to retrieve month with optional separator?

Tags: python, regex

I tried to write python script to retrieve year and month from string.

The requirements are,

- year is fixed at 4 characters
- month is allowed to be two consecutive characters, or one or two characters when followed by a non-numeric value

```py
"""
This is the "search year and month" module.

>>> search_year_month('202301')
True
>>> search_year_month('2023-1')
True
>>> search_year_month('2023-01')
True
>>> search_year_month('20231')
False
"""

import re

_re = re.compile(
    r"(?P<year>\d{4})"
    r"(?P<month>\d{2}|(?<=[^\d])\d{1,2})"
)

def search_year_month(v):
    match = _re.search(v)
    return match is not None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

But, `2023-1` and `2023-01` are failed...
Is there a better way to build regular expressions?

I tried only month part, I got expected result.

```py
"""
This is the "single lookbehind sample" module.

>>> search_lookbehind('01')
True
>>> search_lookbehind('-1')
True
>>> search_lookbehind('-01')
True
>>> search_lookbehind('1')
False
"""

import re

_re = re.compile(
    r"(?P<month>\d{2}|(?<=[^\d])\d{1,2})"
)

def search_lookbehind(v):
    match = _re.search(v)
    return match is not None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Do not post answer as part of your question. If you solved the problem, post regular answer and if that's the one, mark it accepted (even it is yours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) checking for group 2 that holds an optional `-` char.

If there is a value for group 2, then match 1 or 2 digits for the month, else match 2 digits for the month.

```
\b(?P<year>\d{4})(-)?(?P<month>(?(2)\d\d?|\d\d))\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?P<year>\d{4})` Group `year` matching 4 digits
- `(-)?` Optional capture group 2 matching a `-`
- `(?P<month>`  Group `month`

  - `(?` Start a conditional

    - `(2)\d\d?` If we have group 2, match 1 or 2 digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\d\d` Match 2 digits
  - `)` Close the conditional
- `)` Close group `month`
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/imJ7A4/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/S2wipB).

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"\b(?P<year>\d{4})(-)?(?P<month>(?(2)\d\d?|\d\d))\b"
s = ("202301\n"
            "2023-1\n"
            "2023-01\n"
            "20231")

for m in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output

```
{'year': '2023', 'month': '01'}
{'year': '2023', 'month': '1'}
{'year': '2023', 'month': '01'}
```

Comment: very very nice solution! What is especially nice is that there will no longer be a length limit on the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

option 1: search and replace strategy

```
import re
test_string=['202301','2023-1','2023-01','20231']
year=r"^\d{4}"
sep=r"\W+"
for e in test_string:
    year=re.findall(r"^\d{4}",'202301')[0]
    e=re.sub(year,"",e)
    e=re.sub(sep,"",e)
    print(f"year:{year},month:{e}")
```

option 2: regex (all in one)

```
re_all=r"(^\d{4})(?:\W+){0,1}(\d+)"
for e in test_string:
    search_results=re.search(re_all,e)
    print(f"year:{search_results.group(1)},month:{search_results.group(2)}")
```

same outcome:

```
year:2023,month:01
year:2023,month:1
year:2023,month:01
year:2023,month:1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
but, this case, `20231` should not matched.